# How to continue paging after swipe to refresh error?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I am implementing swipe to refresh with the PagingLibrary 3.0.

My repository returns a flow of `PagingData<Item>` which is then exposed as `LiveData` by a viewmodel.

###### Repository

```
override fun getItems(): Flow<PagingData<Item>> {
    val pagingConfig = PagingConfig(pageSize = 20, enablePlaceholders = false)
    val pager = Pager(pagingConfig) {
        IndexedPagingSource(remoteDataSource)
    }
    return pager.flow
}
```

###### ViewModel

```
val itemsStream: LiveData<PagingData<Item>> = repository.getItems()
    .asLiveData()
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

###### Fragment

```
private fun FragmentItemListBinding.bindView() {
    list.adapter = adapter
    list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener { onRefresh() }

    adapter.loadStateFlow
        .onEach { resolveLoadState(it) }
        .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)

    viewModel.itemsStream.observeWithViewLifecycleOwner {
        adapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, it)
    }
}

private fun onRefresh() {
    adapter.refresh()
}

private fun FragmentItemListBinding.resolveLoadState(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
    val adapterEmpty = adapter.itemCount < 1
    swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading && !adapterEmpty
   // resolve all other states here...
}
```

---

The problem is that while the refresh is in progress, the paging stops working (and any ongoing requests are cancelled while the UI stays the same - talking about you `LoadStateFooter`). And it **stops until the refresh succeeds**, which includes failure.

If I don't have any data, I simply display an error screen. But in this case I want to see the previous items and continue paging even after error.

Is there a way to continue paging in the case of a refresh error?

---

The official [architecture components sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/PagingWithNetworkSample) for paging has the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not supported. The generation simply stops working when refresh fails.

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/189967519